# Bias nodes in the GEKKO ANN example

Tags: python, neural-network, gekko

In the ANN example of TCLab B of the Dynamic optimization course webpage (https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabB), has the bias node for every layer been specified in the script? Please let me know which lines represent the bias nodes. If it is not necessary, please explain the reason. Thank you.

```
# -------------------------------------
# build neural network
# -------------------------------------

nin = 2  # inputs
n1 = 2   # hidden layer 1 (linear)
n2 = 2   # hidden layer 2 (nonlinear)
n3 = 2   # hidden layer 3 (linear)
nout = 2 # outputs

# Initialize gekko models
train = GEKKO() 
dyn   = GEKKO()
model = [train,dyn]

for m in model:
    # use APOPT solver
    m.options.SOLVER = 1

    # input(s)
    m.inpt = [m.Param() for i in range(nin)]

    # layer 1 (linear)
    m.w1 = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,nin,n1))
    m.l1 = [[m.Intermediate(sum([m.w1[k,j,i]*m.inpt[j] \
            for j in range(nin)])) for i in range(n1)] \
            for k in range(nout)]

    # layer 2 (tanh)
    m.w2 = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,n1,n2))
    m.l2 = [[m.Intermediate(sum([m.tanh(m.w2[k,j,i]*m.l1[k][j]) \
            for j in range(n1)])) for i in range(n2)] \
            for k in range(nout)]

    # layer 3 (linear)
    m.w3 = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,n2,n3))
    m.l3 = [[m.Intermediate(sum([m.w3[k,j,i]*m.l2[k][j] \
            for j in range(n2)])) for i in range(n3)] \
            for k in range(nout)]

    # outputs
    m.outpt = [m.CV() for i in range(nout)]
    m.Equations([m.outpt[k]==sum([m.l3[k][i] for i in range(n3)]) \
                 for k in range(nout)])

    # flatten matrices
    m.w1 = m.w1.flatten()
    m.w2 = m.w2.flatten()
    m.w3 = m.w3.flatten()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some reasons why you may consider adding bias nodes:

- A bias is like an intercept term in linear regression and are useful to adjust the inputs or internal nodes to achieve a better fit.
- Bias terms are extra parameters that the solver can use to minimize the loss function (objective function).

Some of the reasons that you may not want to add bias nodes:

- They create additional parameters that can create additional extrapolation problems due to over-parameterization and over-fitting
- A bias can shift the inputs or internal nodes up or down to the point that there are vanishing gradients as the solver iterates. This leads to parts of the model that may no longer contribute to differentiating the predictions.
- Deep learning networks may be able to compensate for the lack of bias terms by adjusting the average output.

It can also help to scale the inputs and outputs to between 0 and 1, especially if zero for the input would then equate to zero for the output. With this transformation, you've scaled the variables so that the bias term is zero and you are trying to model the change from zero with activation functions. This method is used in dynamic modeling where you transform equations into "deviation variable" form where the nominal or steady state values are set to zero. The equations track a deviation from that nominal zero starting point.

Here are a few additional suggestions on this topic with [discussion 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185911/why-are-bias-nodes-used-in-neural-networks) and [discussion 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153933/importance-of-the-bias-node-in-neural-networks).

You can add bias terms to your Gekko model such as shown in [example 7 of the 18 Gekko tutorials](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization). The bias term is w2b. Similarly, you could add it for the problem you mentioned as well, although you may only want to try it for the first (input) layer as w1a and w1b.

```py
for m in model:
    # use APOPT solver
    m.options.SOLVER = 1

    # input(s)
    m.inpt = [m.Param() for i in range(nin)]

    # layer 1 (linear)
    m.w1a = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,nin,n1))
    m.w1b = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,nin,n1))
    m.l1 = [[m.Intermediate(sum([m.w1a[k,j,i]*m.inpt[j] + m.w1b[k,j,i] \
            for j in range(nin)])) for i in range(n1)] \
            for k in range(nout)]

    # layer 2 (tanh)
    m.w2a = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,n1,n2))
    m.w2b = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,n1,n2))
    m.l2 = [[m.Intermediate(sum([m.tanh(m.w2a[k,j,i]*m.l1[k][j]) + m.w2b[k,j,i] \
            for j in range(n1)])) for i in range(n2)] \
            for k in range(nout)]

    # layer 3 (linear)
    m.w3a = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,n2,n3))
    m.w3b = m.Array(m.FV, (nout,n2,n3))
    m.l3 = [[m.Intermediate(sum([m.w3a[k,j,i]*m.l2[k][j] + m.w3b[k,j,i] \
            for j in range(n2)])) for i in range(n3)] \
            for k in range(nout)]

    # outputs
    m.outpt = [m.CV() for i in range(nout)]
    m.Equations([m.outpt[k]==sum([m.l3[k][i] for i in range(n3)]) \
                 for k in range(nout)])

    # flatten matrices
    m.w1a = m.w1.flatten()
    m.w2a = m.w2.flatten()
    m.w3a = m.w3.flatten()
    m.w1b = m.w1.flatten()
    m.w2b = m.w2.flatten()
    m.w3b = m.w3.flatten()
```